# Can't Stop Terminal in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I want to stop terminal in VS Code with CTRL + C but instead of stopping it, it shows ^C (GitBash)/copy directory (CMD). Because of that, I decided to kill the terminal. How to deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ctrl + D` to log out of the terminal, and automatically close it.

`Ctrl + C` just sends a SIGINT to the process, which is usually causing it to abort, but it's up to the application to decide.

You can read more about it [here](https://superuser.com/questions/169051/whats-the-difference-between-c-and-d-for-unix-mac-os-x-terminal).